# Informatica B2B MFT console

Tags: informatica

I have a question on Informatica B2B MFT console. 
Could you please let me know how to Trigger a MFT action based on a certain condition, like only if a file (assume trigger file) is present on a particular location then I need to trigger the MFT action.

Please someone share your thoughts.

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: Share your code. Then we will help you.

Comment: Hi I'm asking the outline of the logic on how we can implement this. In fact i'm yet to code this. so asking you guys to get an outline idea. Please share! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Monitor through MFT to check for file creation, this will trigger any MFT job you want by configuring that monitor.